# Flask SQLAlchemy null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a web application and two different environments: prod and staging.

I exported tables from one database to another, from production to staging. Now the staging database got all the tables however, whenever I try to use the staging web application to create a model, I get:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

I then realized that the staging database didn't have any sequences so I copied over the sequences from the prod env to the staging env too. However I still get that error. I'm not sure what the issue is. It's similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225636/integrityerror-error-null-value-in-column-user-id-violates-not-null-constrai) however unlike the answer there I'm exporting the tables from a postgres db to another postgres db.

Any insight would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it seems that you might use a kind database migration tool, it created some additional tables to keep tracking and cause the issue. The solution is that you need to export crucial tables (which you defined on your own) from your old DB then dump to CSV, JSON then, loads to postgresql again.