# How do I have Flask-SQLAlchemy with Postgres, have the primary key not reuse a deleted number?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy with Postgres. I noticed that when I delete a record, the next record will reuse that one's id, which is not ideal for my purposes. Another SO question that  this is the default behavior. In particular, his [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328599/why-isnt-sqlalchemy-creating-serial-columns) discussed the sql behind the scenes. However, when I tested the solution in this problem, it did not work. In fact, postgres was not using `SERIAL` for the primary key. I was having to edit it in `pgadmin` myself. Solutions in other programs mention using a `Sequence` but it is not shown where the sequence is coming from.

So I would hope this code:

```
class Test1(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "test1"

    # id = ... this is what needs to change
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

would not reuse say 3 if record 3 was deleted and another was created like so:

```
i1 = Invoice()
db.session.add(i1)
i2 = Invoice()
db.session.add(i2)
i3 = Invoice()
db.session.add(i3)
db.session.commit()

invs = Invoice.query.all()
for i in invs:
    print(i.id)  # Should print 1,2,3

Invoice.query.filter(id=3).delete()  # no 3 now
db.session.commit()

i4 = Invoice()
db.session.add(i4)
db.session.commit()

invs = Invoice.query.all()
for i in invs:
    print(i.id)  # Should print 1,2,4
```

Other, solutions said to use `autoincrement=False`. Okay, but then how do I determine what the number to set the id to is? Is there a way to save a variable in the class without it being a column:

```
class Test2(db.Model)
    __tablename__ = 'test2'

    id = ...
    last_id = 3

    # code to set last_id when a record is deleted
```

Edit:
So I could (although I do not think I should) use Python to do this. I think this more clearly tries to illustrate what I am trying to do.

```
class Test1(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "test1"

    # id = ... this is what needs to change
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    last_used_id = 30

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = last_used_id + 1
        self.last_used_id +=1

# Not sure if this somehow messes with SQLAlchemy / the db making the id first.
```

This will make any new record not touch an id that was already used.
However, with this I approach, I do encounter the class variable issue behavior of Python. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/are-static-class-variables-possible-in-python)

---

Future self checking: See UUID per @net comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183042/how-can-i-use-uuids-in-sqlalchemy):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `autoincrement=True`. This will automatically increment the id everytime you add a new row.

```py
class Test1(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "test1"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    ....
```

By default Postgres will not reuse ids due to performance issues. Attempting to avoid gaps or to re-use deleted IDs creates horrible performance problems. See the [PostgreSQL wiki FAQ](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_are_there_gaps_in_the_numbering_of_my_sequence.2FSERIAL_column.3F_Why_aren.27t_my_sequence_numbers_reused_on_transaction_abort.3F).

You don't need to keep track of the id. When you call `db.session.add(i4)` and `db.session.commit()` it will automatically insert with the incremented id.

Comment: See my code block above to test this. This did not work when deleting id=4 then making a new record. It would have 4

Comment: I see. If performance is not an issue for you. Consider using uuid version 4 as primary key. That way it will always be unique everytime.

Comment: Okay, I will look into that. That might be the solution. I think I should update my question to this. Let's say I have an invoice with id 10. We email it to a customer.  If we then remove it from the system, it seems to renumber 11 to 10, probably also making 12 to the end point one incorrectly. So I guess this is more of a integrity question than anything? Does this change suggests any other solutions as well to look into. By the way, I see you are a new user. Welcome to SO  friend!

Comment: I didn't quit understand the question. If you delete an invoice the system creates two more? Is the system automatically creating new invoices to replace the deleted one? if I understand your question correctly, maybe you can have another boolen column such as `valid`. Instead of deleting an invoice you can toggle the `valid` column. Then your system can check the `valid` column before send out invoice reminders. Thanks for the welcome!

Comment: See my update. I explain it with python. Sorry, I am just making myself more confused at this point :(

Comment: Does my update make it clearer? I do think I need UUID so I will check that out

Comment: The update actually makes it more complicated. Just let the database take care of id. Don't keep track of it. The `id` is something you shouldn't have worry about. Just let the connection take care of it. Try setting the table id to `id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, unique=True, nullable=False)`.

Comment: I agree but the issue that I am having with that is that if I delete a stale data row for legitamate purposes. It then seems to round the next id down when I create a new one and I do not want it to. Deleted record with id 12 would I hope not make the next created record have an id of 12.  The uuid method does work, but I will explore that you are saying about just having the db track the last used number

Comment: That is not they way Postgres should be indexing. It should never reuse old numbers even if the previous one was deleted. It should always increment.

Comment: So the edited answer is correct. I am pretty sure it is the `unique=True` I feel dumb for having forgotten this. :( Thanks so much net!