Postgres SQL Internal Server Error: Id seen as non-null
I'm trying to setup a post request with SQL Alchemy where I can update entries in a User table. I'm running into an issue where the user_id is violating the non_null constraint
The error:
(pg8000.exceptions.DatabaseError) {'S': 'ERROR', 'V': 'ERROR', 'C': '23502', 'M': 'null value in column "id" of relation "User" violates not-null constraint', 'D': 'Failing row contains (null, string, string, string, string, string, CA, string, string, string, string, 0, Temp, Temp, Temp, t, 2024-06-24 11:55:55.40777, 2024-06-24 11:55:55.40777, t).', 's': 'public', 't': 'User', 'c': 'id', 'F': 'execMain.c', 'L': '2009', 'R': 'ExecConstraints'}


For context, I've set up a One-to-Many relationship with a State table (as the Parent) and the User table (as the Child). Prior to setting up the relationship, the database would create a new user_id upon every entry. After setting up this relationship, I now get this error
here is my relevant code
models.py
class State(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'state'

    state_code = Column(String(2), primary_key=True)
    state_Name = Column(String(150), nullable=False)

    #relationship 
    # user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('User.user_ID'))
    children = relationship("User", back_populates="parent")
    
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'User'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ### - UI
    first_name = Column(String(50))
    last_name = Column(String(50))
    address_line_1 = Column(String(100))
    address_line_2 = Column(String(100))
    city = Column(String(50))
    
    zip = Column(String(10))
    login_name = Column(String(100))
    email = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    mobile_phone_num = Column(String(15))
    grade_level = Column(Integer)
    has_adhd = Column(Boolean)
    ### - UI

    ### - Google Auth
    google_id = Column(String(100))
    google_name = Column(String(100))
    google_profile_url = Column(String(255))
   

    is_active = Column(Boolean, nullable=False) #Default is True
    creation_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False) # Current date user logs in, hardcoded
    last_update_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False) # Current date user logs off, hardcoded
    
    #Relationships
    state_code = Column(String(2), ForeignKey('state.state_code'))
    parent = relationship("State", back_populates="children")

main.py
##Schema##
class StateBase(BaseModel):
    state_name: str
class UserBase(BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    address_line_1: str
    address_line_2: str
    city: str
    state_code: str
    zip: str
    login_name: str
    email: str
    mobile_phone_num: str
    grade_level: int
    has_adhd: bool

    google_id: str
    google_name: str
    google_profile_url: str
    
    is_active: bool
    creation_date: datetime
    last_update_date: datetime

## Cognifin
@app.post("/State")
async def create_state(state:StateBase, db: db_dependency):
    db_state = models.State(
        State_name = state.State_name
        )
    db.add(db_state)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_state)

@app.post("/User")
async def create_user(user:UserBase, db: db_dependency):
    
    db_user = models.User(
        ##UI Elements
        first_name = user.first_name,
        last_name = user.last_name,
        address_line_1 = user.address_line_1,
        address_line_2 = user.address_line_2,
        city = user.city,
        state_code = user.state_code,
        zip = user.zip,
        login_name = user.login_name,
        email = user.email,
        mobile_phone_num = user.mobile_phone_num,
        grade_level = user.grade_level,
        has_adhd = user.has_adhd,

        ### - Google Auth
        google_id = "Temp",
        google_name = "Temp",
        google_profile_url = "Temp",
        ##UI backend
        is_active = True,
        creation_date = datetime.now(),
        #DDBL CHECK WITH KRISHNA
        last_update_date = datetime.now()
        )
    db.add(db_user)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_user)

I think the issue's cause "id" is primary, so I tried setting Nullable to True:
Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=True),

This doesn't seem like good practice though, and it didn't work regardless, so any advice would be rlly appreciated

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328599/why-isnt-sqlalchemy-creating-serial-columns
I think this question/answer should solve your problem.

Use your favorite database management tool (DBeaver, pgAdmin_4, ...) to inspect the id column in the User table on the server. The DDL for that column should not be simply id integer NOT NULL. Feel free to [edit] your question to show the CREATE TABLE statement that your tool displays.

Make your id an identity column:
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

Should become:
id = Column(Integer, Identity(), primary_key=True)

See the manual for further explanation.
Don't use a serial or sequence, let the database handle this for you by using identity.
